# Always Populating CheckboxColumn in Datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 `Datagridview` and that is DataGridView1 and 2 the First one is populated through Form Load and the Second One will Populate based on `Datagridview` Selected,

Here is my code I’m using:

```
Dim checkBoxColumn As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
        Dim i As Integer
        i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
        Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;password=admin1950;database=fulldatabase")
        Dim sql As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("select SubControls from subpriv where mainformname = '" & DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value & "';", con)
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
        Dim adapter As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
        con.Open()
        adapter.SelectCommand = sql
        adapter.Fill(ds, "MyTable")
        DataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        con.Close()
            checkBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Approve"
            checkBoxColumn.Width = 120
            checkBoxColumn.Name = "checkBoxColumn"
            DataGridView2.Columns.Insert(0, checkBoxColumn)
```

But my problem here is that, my codes always populating `checkboxcolumn` every time I select in DatagridView1.

My question is how can limit only to 1`Checkboxcolumn`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use the CellContentClick event, in this case I would do the following:

```
Private Sub dgvdatos_CellContentClick(sender As DataGridView, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvdatos.CellContentClick
    If TypeOf (sender.CurrentCell) Is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell And e.RowIndex = 0 Then
  'DO STUFF
End If End Sub
```